# Connect-MSGraph command unable to execute in Azure Functions powershell core 6

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

I have an azure function with Powershell core 6 environment create,

Wanted to run some of the MS graph powershell modules like "Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages"
but this requires token which i tried to use "Connect-MSGraph" but when executed got the following error
Error:
Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.): Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

can anyone help me in the fix or correct me if I am doing it wrong at any point.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, I don't know how to run `Get-IntuneManagedDevice` with token in azure powershell function. But I can provide a workaround below for your reference(use rest api to get the same result in azure powershell function which you expected).

**1.** Open fildder and run the command `Get-IntuneManagedDevice` in powershell, we can see the command request the microsoft graph api in the backend. The api is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices` and this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) is its document (**you do not need to do this step**).

**2.** We need to add the permission for your app registered in azure ad.

[image]
After add the permission, don't forget grant admin consent for it.

**3.** We can find the graph api just support Delegated permission type but not support Application permission type according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0).
[image]
**So we can't use client credential as grant type to get the access token(we can't just use secret key to get access token) as you mentioned in the comments above**. We need to request the access token by password grant type, so use the command below to get access token:

```
$AppId = 'xxx'
$AppSecret = 'xxx'
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
$TenantName = "xxx"
$username = "xxx"
$password = "xxx"
$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$Body = @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    scope = $Scope
    username = $username
    password = $password
    grant_type = 'password'
}
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
}
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat
$Request.access_token
```

**4.** In step 1 we know the command `Get-IntuneManagedDevice` request the graph api in the backend, so we just need to request the graph api and then we can get the result.

```
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices"
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
$result.value
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this.
was trying if we could make this work as well

Answer (score 0):

Could you you please let's know if you have already created the application, secret key etc. which are needed to be created prior to access Graph API? I have created a blog explaining "How to create mailbox folders in Exchange Online mailboxes using Graph API and PowerShell". At the first portion, I am explaining the procedure to create the application in Azure tenant. Please check that. Hope, it helps you

[Create Custom Folder in Exchange Online Mailboxes using Graph API using Windows PowerShell](http://cloudcompute.info/create-custom-folder-in-exchange-online-mailboxes-using-graph-api-using-windows-powershell/)

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Yes i have the application id and secret key

i am updating the Update-MSGraphEnvironment to update teh application id 
and using Connect-MSGraph -clientsecret $secret to connect

Comment: Also i went through the link, to use secret key in rest method is working , but how to i pass that token to the module "Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages"

Answer (score 0):

How about the following way:

1. Downlead the latest release of Intune Power Shell SDK from the following GitHub repository
   https://github.com/Microsoft/Intune-PowerShell-SDK/releases
2. [Unblock the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-6)
3. Import the module in PowerShell

   Import-Module .\Microsoft.Graph.Intune.psd1Import-Module .\Microsoft.Graph.Intune.psd1
4. Connect MS Grpah

   Connect-MSGraph -AdminConsent
5. Try the In-Tune managed devices connection (Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages)

Thanks,
Manu